# Fuzzy auto complete in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, fuzzy-search

Few days ago, I download a new version of Eclipse(4.4.2), and found a new feature on that, is fuzzy auto complete *(as the bottom picture in screenshot below)*.

[image: Screenshot]

When I switch to another workspace, this feature has gone, it only allow prefix to auto complete *(as the top picture in screenshot)*.

Did any one know where is this feature's setting in eclipse?

Comment: Please include the photo as you mention above

Comment: I'm tried, but not found i wanted.@RohitGupta

Comment: @Brian Rogers, thank you very much for help me edit this post for more readable.

Answer (score 7):

After i half delete/half reserve file in .metadata directory, I found this feature setting in Eclipse finally. Open Preferences dialog, navigate to Code Recommenders->Completions, check the option [Enable intelligent code completion] and [Subwords-Completion Processor].

Comment: for those who don't find this setting: install the [code recommenders plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/)